# Meteor: Best way to create a new document in a collection before visiting a route?

Tags: meteor

Every time a user visits a specific route, I'd like for a new document to get created that will act as a "draft" that the user will edit until they decide to publish it.

Another way to think about this is that I want to redirect a user to a new page displaying the document after a successful insert of the document.

When I phrase it like that, I think I've basically answered my own question. In this case I would just call a Meteor method that creates and inserts the new document, then in the callback method I would use iron-router's `Router.go` method to redirect to the url using the new _id as a parameter. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to get collection created automatically upon visiting a route. What happen if user visit the route unintentionally?

Nevertheless, you can achieve it by inserting a document on publish function and it will get created upon Meteor.subscribe.

```
Meteor.publish('test-draft', function(options){

  var _id = Test.insert({a: 'b'});

  return Test.find({_id: _id})

})
```

Comment: Visiting the route unintentionally is the same as starting a new document unintentionally. I intended to create a limit on the number of "drafts" a user could have.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're doing correctly, I think the easiest thing would be to just create an object and put it in a `Session` variable and not mess with creating a document in a collection until you're done editing it.

You can create the object and stick it into `Session` in `Templates.myTemplate.rendered = function() { ... }`. And then when it's been satisfactorily edited and submitted pass the Session variable to a Method that inserts it as a new document.

Comment: This sounds like a more promising route, the main benefit is that if the user visits the route a document isn't created automatically until they enter something. The idea is that usually a user would not edit the document in one sitting, but could rather leave and return to the page multiple times, each time saving the draft until they are ready to "publish".